# How to run a unit test task before uploadArchives

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got this config to upload artifact to local maven repository.

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            pom {
                groupId = 'group'
                artifactId = 'android'
                version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            }
            repository(url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath)
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to run all the unit tests before uploading the artifact. I'm tired of running the unit tests task manually every time, so I thought `uploadArchives` task should depend on `testDebugUnitTest`. The test tasks comes from Android library plugin.

```
uploadArchives {
    dependsOn testDebugUnitTest
}
```

Unfortunately this configuration doesn't work. Is it possible to configure it the way I want?

Comment: I do this for all my apps: `uploadArchives.dependsOn 'testDebugUnitTest'`

Comment: You're correct, single quotes are needed to get it working. You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this to automate my tests. The basic syntax here is `<your task> dependsOn '<this task>'` in order for your entire build process to finish successfully.

You want something like this:

```
uploadArchives.dependsOn 'testDebugUnitTest'
```